# vb6 WebView2 get innerhtml and http cookies data

Tags: vb6, webview2

1. How do I Get the Login Cookies when am logged into a site?

I am searching for answers and now turned to StackOverflow pro members for your expertise and help to get this out of the way so I can move on to making my software.

i need to get the cookies login/visit /get/post anything how do i get it using the new webview2 browser kindly shed some light please anyone

```
Option Explicit
'Note, that this Demo requires the properly registered RC6-Binaries
'and in addition an installed "Chromium-Edge" (in its "evergreen" WebView2-incarnation)
'installable from its official MS-Download-URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=2124703
 
Private WithEvents WV As cWebView2 'declare a WebView-variable WithEvents
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Visible = True '<- it's important, that the hosting TopLevel-Form is visible...
                 '...(and thus the Child-PicBox indirectly as well) - before we Bind the PicBox to the WebView
  
  Set WV = New_c.WebView2 'create the instance
  If WV.BindTo(picWV.hWnd) = 0 Then MsgBox "couldn't initialize WebView-Binding": Exit Sub
 
'  Set WV = New_c.WebView2(picWV.hWnd) 'create the instance
'  If WV Is Nothing Then MsgBox "couldn't initialize WebView-Binding": Exit Sub
 
End Sub
'*** VB-Command-Button-Handlers

Private Sub cmdNavigate_Click()
   WV.Navigate "https://google.com" '<- alternatively WV.jsProp("location.href") = "https://google.com" would also work
   
   'the call below, just to show that our initially added js-functions, remain "in place" - even when we re-navigate to something else
   WV.jsRunAsync "test", 2, 3
End Sub

Private Sub WV_NavigationCompleted(ByVal IsSuccess As Boolean, ByVal WebErrorStatus As Long)
Debug.Print "NavigationCompleted welaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

End Sub




Private Sub picWV_Resize() 'when the hosting picBox got resized, we have to call a syncSize-method on the WebView
  If Not WV Is Nothing Then WV.SyncSizeToHostWindow
End Sub
Private Sub picWV_GotFocus() 'same thing here... when the hosting picBox got the focus, we tell the WebView about it
  If Not WV Is Nothing Then WV.SetFocus
End Sub

'*** the above two EventHandlers (of the hosting VB-PicBox-Container-Ctl) are basically all what's needed "GUI-Binding-wise"

'*** the rest of the EventHandlers below, are raised by the WebView-instance itself



Private Sub WV_InitComplete()
  Debug.Print "WV_InitComplete"
End Sub

'Private Sub WV_NavigationCompleted(ByVal IsSuccess As Long, ByVal WebErrorStatus As Long)
  'Debug.Print "WV_NavigationCompleted"
'End Sub

Private Sub WV_DocumentComplete()
  Debug.Print "WV_DocumentComplete"
 
End Sub

Private Sub WV_GotFocus(ByVal Reason As eWebView2FocusReason)
  Debug.Print "WV_GotFocus", Reason
End Sub

Private Sub WV_JSAsyncResult(Result As Variant, ByVal Token As Currency, ByVal ErrString As String)
  Debug.Print "WV_JSAsyncResult "; Result, Token, ErrString
   Text2.Text = Result
End Sub

Private Sub WV_JSMessage(ByVal sMsg As String, ByVal sMsgContent As String, oJSONContent As cCollection)
  Debug.Print sMsg, sMsgContent
  Select Case sMsg
    Case "btn1_click": MsgBox "txt1.value: " & WV.jsProp("document.getElementById('txt1').value")
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub WV_LostFocus(ByVal Reason As eWebView2FocusReason)
  Debug.Print "WV_LostFocus", Reason
End Sub

Private Sub WV_UserContextMenu(ByVal ScreenX As Long, ByVal SreenY As Long)
  Debug.Print "WV_UserContextMenu", ScreenX, SreenY
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like you are asking multiple different things. You should keep these questions focused on one thing only. Feel free to post multiple different but related questions.  You can also edit this one to focus it more.

Comment: please check updated